# Magento 2 graphql route, Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: magento2, magento-graphql

I am working on Magento 2 graphql, magento version is 2.4.6. I am getting this error when I try to fetch category page through route resolver;
[image]

Route resolver works for cms and product pages though;

my query is

[image]

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Products/DataProvider/ExtractDataFromCategoryTree.php
```

this file line#41 is causing this issue but the code here seams fine
[image]